# Writing User Data to Firebase After Creating New User Account

Tags: swift, database, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to write the users information to firebase's database after using the create user function `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser`

Under this function I attempt to insert the data into the database like this:

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

                if error == nil

                {   
                    let email = self.emailField.text
                    let firstName = self.firstnameField.text
                    let lastName = self.lastnameField.text      


                    self.ref.child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["firstName": firstName,"lastName": lastName,"email": email])               
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createaccountLandingPage", sender: sender)
                }
```

It also may be important to mention that under my view controller I create the reference to the database using:

`var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users") //root database`

My outlets are all correct, but I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Any suggestions on what I may be doing incorrectly?

EDIT** Here is all my code in the signup view controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users") //root database

@IBOutlet weak var firstnameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastnameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmpasswordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject)

{

    if self.confirmpasswordField.text != self.passwordField.text

    {

    }

    else

    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil

            {

                let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.uid
                let email = self.emailField.text
                let firstName = self.firstnameField.text
                let lastName = self.lastnameField.text

                self.ref.child("users").child("\(user)").setValue(["firstName": firstName,"lastName": lastName,"email": email])


                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createaccountLandingPage", sender: sender)

            }

            else

            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT*** here is a screenshot of the error

EDIT**** here is a screenshot of my podfile and when it is updated I recieve no errors in the terminal.

EDIT***** Screenshots of console.

[1stScreenshotConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Nz1.jpg)
[2ndScreenshotConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEaPx.jpg)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you take out the self.performegue stuff?

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia yeah :/ but if i take out the database stuff I do not get an error..should I create a separate function to do it maybe? (this is Sarah's friend responding, we are working on this together)

Comment: Okay I see, I'm curious to see where you are running that block of code.

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia I added all of my code to the post. Hopefully this makes my question a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @SarahVictoriaSnyder okay I think I see your problem. I'll write my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a reference to your database like this

```
Var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

Then you initialize your database in your viewDidLoad like this

```
Ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

I wrote the whole code below, excuse the syntax errors because I am answering your question on an iPad.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref = FIRDatabaseReference! //create a reference for your database


@IBOutlet weak var firstnameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastnameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmpasswordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

//initialize your database
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject)

{

    if self.confirmpasswordField.text != self.passwordField.text

    {

    }

    else

    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil

            {
                let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.uid //get the users UID after registering
                let email = self.emailField.text
                let firstName = self.firstnameField.text
                let lastName = self.lastnameField.text

                self.ref.child("users").child("\(user!)").setValue(["firstName": "\(firstName!)", "lastName": "\(lastName!)", "email": "\(email!)"])

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createaccountLandingPage", sender: sender)

            }

            else

            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't realize when I was reading the firebase IOS read and write guide that the ref.FIRDatabase.database().reference() needed to go under view did load. However, I am still getting errors when using the line of code: self.ref.child("users).child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "email": email])

Comment: Are you able to register the user at least?

Comment: @cyrillvargarcia yes

Comment: Aahhh, where are you getting the users.uid? I'

Comment: So i created a variable `let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.user` and use the variable `user` instead of `user?.uid`

Comment: Oh I think its uid instead of user, sorry try that

Comment: So it would be `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.uid`

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the consol when you get the error please?

Comment: Okay, got it. In the consol it says that your framework is not properly linked. Did you add the Firebae/database framework in your pods file?

Comment: Yes I have also made sure it's all updated.. I provided a screenshot of my pod file

Comment: I'm comparing your methods with my method in one of my projects with Firebase and everything is almost identical. According to the console, it says that `Framework is not currently linked`.. Your pod file looks fine, I'm assuming the issue might be your GooglePlist file that you imported. Try importing it again and maybe that would work. And if the error persist, can you take another screenshot of the whole console where the errors are listed.

Comment: I am also assuming you configured your app with Firebase in your AppDelegate correct?

Comment: i just imported my googleplist file again and the problem still occurs... I have a slight feeling the problem could be with how I configured it through my appdelegate... all i did was insert a line of code ' import Firebase ' and under didfinishlaunchingwithoptions i put ' FIRApp.configure() '

Comment: You can see the code for this in the first screenshot... is this correct? @CyrillvarGarcia

Comment: Yea, but I want to see the console. At the top left side of your screen, you have like an magnifying glass, and kinda like a message box, click on that little message box icon and under it click on debug after you run your program. That should give us some more details of what is going on.

Comment: okay i have added the first and last part of the debugging... it is rather large and i am unable to post more than two links @CyrillvarGarcia

Comment: So the error said `Terminating app due to uncaught exception, Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at lastname.` I made changes under                    `self.ref.child("users").child("\(user!)").setValue(["firstName": "\(firstName!)", "lastName": "\(lastName!)", "email": "\(email!)"])`
see if that will work. I tested it myself and it worked like a charm! let me know if something iss till not right

Comment: Worked great!! Thanks for all the help!!